# Firebase push notifications come with no sound on some devices

Tags: android, ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Could somebody please share some experience with me, maybe you've faced the same problem some time.
I've set up push notifications for my app via Firebase and everything's been working fine. But recently i've started receiving the issues from users that on some devices push notifications come silently.
One of my users has Samsung Galaxy J3 on Android 7.1, another one has iPhone.

Unfortunately i don't have physical access to devices to reproduce the issue myself. They told me that they already checked settings for notifications and settings inside `applications/settings/my-app/notifications`
A've also run emulator with Android 7.1, and there is a sound ) I don't know what else to do )

That's how i send notifications from nodejs

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
// ... some config gets loaded
// Init app
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(credentials),
    databaseURL: config.fcmDatabase
});

// And there is a fragment with request:
static sendFirebaseNotification(token, text, message) {
        const payload = {
            title: message.eventName,
            body: text,
            sound: 'default',
            color: '#ffffff'
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token.token, {
            notification: payload,
            data: {
                event: message.event,
                eventName: message.eventName
            }
        }).then(response => {
            logger.info(`Message sent: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
            return true;
        });
    }
```

Maybe someone has faced something the same by any chance?
I really don't know what else to check, because it works fine on almost all devices.